# parse int to datetime with carbon

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I have an example value of : `20160530105130`
Which I want to convert to a datetime.

I have tried `Carbon::createFromFormat('Ym',$value)`
But that just errors.

I also tried with timestamp, but again error.

Anyone have an idea how I can achive this?

Comment: The format appears to be `YmdHis`…?!

Comment: @deceze Isn't the format, what you want it to become?

Comment: Come again, please?

Comment: @deceze when I have converted the date, I want just the year and month. So I added Ym?

Comment: You're trying to parse a string to a `Carbon` instance. A `Carbon` instance can't just be a year and month. You also need to specify the complete format for the complete string. You can then format the `Carbon` instance again to your desired format.

Comment: @deceze if you add it as an answer, i will accept that :D

Comment: @andrelange91 : If you only want the year and month, you should set the day and time to a fixed value and not take the values from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('YmdHis', "$value")
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a DateTime or Carbon object from the string and use the year and month there.

```
$str = '20160530105130';

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Ym????????',$str);

var_dump($dt);
//object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-05-01 00:00:00.000000"
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/bOJdU

With carbon:

```
$str = '20160530105130';

$dt = Carbon::createFromFormat('!Ym????????',$str);
echo $dt;  //2016-05-01 00:00:00
```

Alternatively, the string can also be completely parsed with DateTime. The day and time can then be set to the desired values using the modify method. This variant makes it easier to read what is being done.

```
$str = '20160530105130';
$dt = date_create($str)->modify('first day of this month 00:00');
//object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-05-01 00:00:00.000000"
```